# defining a field for current year in web2py using datetime

Tags: web2py

I am completely new to Web2Py and have the following problem:

I am trying to define a database and have the current year as a field which should be automatically filled in using datetime.

But when I try to open the database and look at the entries I get a traceback which I do not understand (see below).

Edit: I think it has to do something with strftime having only one argument. When I am using strftime("%Y%m%d") it is working perfectly. But I really only need the current year.

Thank you

**Code**

import datetime

```
       db.define_table('orders',            
                    Field("current_year", "string",default=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y"),Label=T('Current Year'), readable=True, writable=False))
```

**Code using IS_DATETIME**

After reading the web2py documentation I also tried this:

import datetime

Field('current_year', 'string', label=T('Current Year'), default=IS_DATETIME(format=T('%Y')),readable=True, writable=False))

**Traceback:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PyCatUB/web2py/applications/contacts/controllers/appadmin.py", line 269, in select
    *fields, limitby=(start, stop))
  File "/home/PyCatUB/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/objects.py", line 2020, in select
    return adapter.select(self.query, fields, attributes)
  File "/home/PyCatUB/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/sqlite.py", line 123, in select
    return super(SQLiteAdapter, self).select(query, fields, attributes)
  File "/home/PyCatUB/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 1296, in select
    return self._select_aux(sql,fields,attributes)
  File "/home/PyCatUB/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 1253, in _select_aux
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/home/PyCatUB/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 1388, in execute
    return self.log_execute(*a, **b)
  File "/home/PyCatUB/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 1382, in log_execute
    ret = self.get_cursor().execute(command, *a[1:], **b)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 66, in convert_timestamp
    datepart, timepart = val.split(" ")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: I think it has to do something with strftime having only one argument. When I am using strftime("%Y%m%d") it is working perfectly. But I really only need the current year.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Field('current_year', 'string', label=T('Current Year'),
>       default=IS_DATETIME(format=T('%Y')),
>       readable=True, writable=False))
> ```

Above, `IS_DATETIME` is a validator. It is meant to be used with the `requires` attribute of the field. You cannot use it with the `default` attribute. In that case, when you do an insert, it will simply insert the string representation of that validator object, which will look something like `'<gluon.validators.IS_DATETIME object at 0x000002202AC13CC0>'`. That string is obviously not a valid datetime string, so you get an exception when `dbapi2.py` attempts to parse it as a timestamp.

If you only want to store the year, a better approach is probably just to use an integer type and store just the year as an integer:

```
Field('current_year', 'integer', default=request.now.year)
```

As noted in the comment above, SQLite does not allow you to change the type of an existing field, so if you want to use the name "current_year" for the field, first drop the existing table and let web2py re-create it from scratch with the new field type.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I fixed this. For some reason, web2py did not like the tag "current_year". I changed this to "curyear"  because I had the feeling current_year might be a reserved word - and it worked. Could that be the reason?

Comment: There is nothing special about `current_year`. Probably you tried to change the type of the field, which SQLite does not allow (it simply leaves the old type). When you changed the field name to `curyear`, it instead created a completely new column with the new type.

Comment: Ah, ok! That makes total sense...Thank you!